# Registering an event listener on an element

Tags: javascript, css, css-selectors, prototypejs, dom-events

This is the structure of HTML. I have to add an event listener when user click on div with className "next_button". I try to add an event listener by using prototype.

```
<div id="horizontal_carousel2">
  <div class="previous_button"></div>  
  <div class="container" >
    <ul>
       <li></li>
       <li></li>
       <li></li>
       <li></li>

    </ul>
    <div id="spinner2" style="display: block;"><br /></div>
  </div>
  <div class="next_button"></div>
</div>
```

This is the script which executes on load:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
Event.observe(window, 'load', function() {
            $$("#horizontal_carousel .next_button").first().observe( 'click',tezt());

});

function tezt()
{
    alert("calling me");
}
</script>
```

The problem is "calling me" alerted as the window load completes. I am not able to figure out the problem. What am I missing? I have to show alert message when user click on next button.. T

Comment: Try `.observe('click', tezt)` (ie get rid of the `()` after tezt).

Comment: Please, call me Crescent. Also, you're welcome. I'll leave it to someone else to explain *why* it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second parameter to observe should be a reference to a function.  When you passed tezt() as the second parameter, you **executed** tezt() and passed **its result** to observe.